# How to get value from dropdown list

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to get value from dropdown box into variable and then store it. I'm new to Flask and cant find anything in the documents about it. 
But I dont know how to get the value from dropdown list with request.form or any other why in that matter.

My flask code in app.py

```
@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def add_entry():
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        abort(401)
    title = request.form['title']
    link  = request.form['link']
    shown  = request.form['shown']

    #I hardcoded the id here too see basic function.

    kate = Category.query.filter_by(id = 2).first()
    add_into = Entries(title, link, shown, kate)
    db.session.add(add_into)
    db.session.commit()
```

And here is the html for it.

```
<form action="{{ url_for('add_entry') }}" method=post class="add-entry custom">
  <dl>
    <dt>Title:
    <dd><input type=text size=120 name=title>
    <dt>Link:
    <dd><input type=text size=120 name=link>
    <dt>Shown:
    <dd><input type=text size=120 name=shown>
    <label for="customDropdown">Category</label>
    <select style="display:none;" id="customDropdown">
      {% for c in cate %}
        {% if c.id == 1 %}
          <option id="{{ c.name }}" name="{{ c.name }}" SELECTED>{{ c.name }}</option>
        {% else %}
          <option>{{ c.name }}</option>
        {% endif %}

      {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <dd><input class="success button" type=submit value=Post it!>
    </dl>
</form>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A select tag, like an input tag, needs a "name" attribute on it if you wish to have the value passed as form data.

```
<select name="name" style="display:none;" id="customDropdown">
```

Now, you should be able to access it through `request.form['name']` as you have been your input elements.